# Get and update usermeta in wordpress onclick

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to make a feature to my website. When the user presses a link leads it to a PHP file. in the URL is a request, like this:

```
    <a href="'. plugins_url() .'/gps_konkurranse/gps_konkurranse.phpfunnet=true&user_ID='. $user_ID .'" target="_blank">
```

in the file opened must run a php function that retrieves existing user meta, adds 1 and updates the same user meta.

This is the code I have so far. Can someone help me

```
    <?php
    if($_GET['funnet'] == 'true'){
        $funn = get_user_meta($_GET['user_ID'], 'gps_funn', true );
        $funn++
        update_user_meta( $_GET['user_ID'], 'gps_funn', $funn );

    }

    ?>
```

this code is in a standalone php file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your code works properly, it looks like you are missing a question mark in your URL. It should read:

```
gps_konkurranse.php?funnet=true
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not the only mistake, the rest of the code does not work either.

I think there is something wrong with the communication to wordpress functions, but can not seem to figure out how to get to it.